# How do I include glib in a project I am using cmake for

Tags: cmake, package, gtk, glib

Source Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <driver.hpp>
#include <decrypt_util.hpp>
#include <encrypt_util.hpp>
#include <util.hpp>

GtkWidget     *window1;
GtkWidget     *fixed1;
GtkWidget     *label1;
GtkWidget     *button1;
GtkWidget     *decryptbt;
GtkBuilder    *builder;





int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file ("Attempt.glade");
  //Connects glade file with C++ code
  window1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));
  //Creates pop up window, window is defined as a widget.
  g_signal_connect(window1, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  //Makes the window x stop the program from running further
  gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
  //Connects signals from gui to code, on button clicked and GetCommandLineA

  fixed1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "fixed1"));
  button1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button1"));
  decryptbt = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "decryptbt"));
  label1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "label1"));

  gtk_widget_show(window1);

  gtk_main();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void on_button1_clicked (GtkButton *b){
  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL(label1), (const gchar* ) "Hello World");
}
```

Cmakelists.list

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7...3.18)

if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.12)
    cmake_policy(VERSION ${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION})
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(ezip      VERSION 1.0
                  DESCRIPTION "AES encyption"
                  LANGUAGES CXX)

include_directories(include)

set(SOURCES src/driver.cpp src/util.cpp src/decrypt_util.cpp src/encrypt_util.cpp)
set(GUI src/stuff.cpp)
find_package(Boost 1.6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)




include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(ezip ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(ezip PUBLIC Boost::filesystem)
target_link_libraries (ezip PUBLIC Eigen3::Eigen)
add_executable(GUI1.0 ${GUI})
target_link_libraries(GUI1.0 ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

I have tried many variations of target_link_libraries and find_package but none of them have worked. I know that the package name is libglib2.0-0. But other than that I am taking shots in the dark. Any information would be helpful. I have attempted find_package using simply GLIB2.0 and other variations and I have a terminal output for the package location. If that would be helpful. My error code is

```
home/dellgato/ezip/src/stuff.cpp:6:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/GUI1.0.dir/build.make:82: CMakeFiles/GUI1.0.dir/src/stuff.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:124: CMakeFiles/GUI1.0.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You forgot to include into the question post the **exact error message**.

Comment: I am relatively new to stack overflow and coding in general. Do you have antyhing to help with this?

Comment: So the problem not with glib, but with **GTK**. The module [FindGTK.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTK.html) (which is used by `find_package(GTK)`) sets variables `GTK_INCUDE_DIR` and `GTK_LIBRARIES`. But you use `GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS` for unknown reason..

Comment: After I remove the s, the problem stays the same. The website I read this off of had it as DIRS

Comment: `GTK_INCUDE_DIR` differs from `GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS` not only by ending `s`, but also in `3`. BTW, you can easily detect whether variable is correct one by printing its value (via `message()` command). An empty value usually means that you use **wrong variable**.